# Pros/Cons of using 'ellipsoidal' for calculating geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geometry

When I have found geometry attributes in the past, I've found my distances are often out by quite a lot unless I use an ellipsoidal CRS to calculate them. Why is this the case?

Should I be using ellipsoidal or is there something wrong with what I'm doing. What is the advantage/disadvantage of using 'ellipsoidal' on QGIS to calculate geometry attributes?

Comment: What distances are you talking about? Which CRS are you using?

Comment: Most of my stuff is loaded in using BNG, but when calculating distances using the layer CRS gives massively different values to reality.

Comment: Again: What distances are you talking about? Which CRS are you using?

Comment: My CRS is British national grid. The distances are areas/perimeters.

Comment: So, you're trying to calculate the circumfence of the Atlantic Ocean using EPSG 27700? Or the diameter of the pond in your backyard? Also, which distances do you compare with?

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to this. I didn't realise that's what you're asking!
I'm finding the areas and perimeters of British business parks, so in the order of 3 km^2 area and about 2 or 3 km perimeter. I compare with google maps distances

Comment: Well, can you give an example for the "massively different values to reality"?

Comment: Usually about 60% difference - ie going from about 3km^2 in ellipsoidal to 4.8 km^2 in layer CRS calculations

Comment: @Alex - Ellipsoidal calculations are used for long distances as it takes into account the curvature of the Earth; planimetric projections calculates the distance as if it was on a flat plane which can be fine for short local distances. There's plenty of information regarding this on GIS:SE and online.

Comment: You're comparing geodetic area calculation to Cartesian area in Web Mercator at high latitudes? Web Mercator should never be trusted for distance.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify what that means - does that mean I should or shouldn't be using ellipsoidal for distances?

Comment: Quite the opposite. Area calculation in Web Mercator is useless (the poles do not have infinite area). If you're going to validate area, it should be with an Equal Area projection.